# Why does an old, personal MacBook suddenly want MDM credentials on re-install?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, snow-leopard, automated-device-enrollment

Resetting an old MacBook Pro - really old - it originally came with Snow Leopard.  Using a USB based Mojave installer, which I have used before and is the last thing that stably runs on this box.

On full reset - NVRAM, SMC, disk, everything, installer loads normally but then does the MDM prompt and tells me my computer is managed by a company in New York.

Key details - this is a personal MacBook, bought new years ago.  I have done this re-install in the past without issue.

Have researched various issues with MDM and used computers, get all that.  Question though is how something now is on this box that thinks it needs MDM to re-install.  It has never been used outside my possession.

Working the various procedures indicated to try to remove/bypass the MDM prompts.  Curious as if anyone has determined on a personally owned computer how it magically starts to use MDM.

Thanks

Comment: Did you originally purchase this MBP new or was it purchased second-hand?

Comment: You bought it "new" from... where?  If from Apple, provide Apple with proof of ownership and they should remove even something that old from ABM.

Comment: All MacBook Pro models, capable of running Snow Leopard, can not be upgraded to Mojave. I assume here some sort of hack has not taken place.